# При обновлении ячейки при помощи reloadRowsAtIndexPaths таблица немного скролится

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

(Сама проблема описана в самом низу)

У меня есть таблица у которой ячейки переменной высоты. В сториборде ячейка кастомизирована и там всё держится на констрейнтах. В каждой ячейке высота меняется в зависимости от контента (картинки и текст разной высоты).

Чтобы это работало я добавил в класс контроллера таблицы такой код:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        api.getUserPosts(afterGetFeed)
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250.0
    }
```

В каждой ячейке есть кнопка для лайков.

```swift
cell.likeBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedVC.likeClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, на сервер отправляется команда

```swift
    @IBAction func likeClick (sender: UIButton){
        let ind = sender.tag //достаю номер строки
        let postid = allposts[ind].postid! 
        let params = ["cell" : ind] //тут передаётся индекс ячейки в следующий метод, который вызовется после получения ответа сервера
        api.updateLike(pistid: postid, params: params, afterLikeUpdateFunc: afterUpdateLike)
    }
```

обрабатывается ответ и выводится новое количество лайков на кнопке. Я меняю все эти значения в массиве, а потом просто вызываю метод обновления:

```swift
    func afterUpdateLike (data: NSData, params: NSDictionary){
        let ind : Int = params["cell"] as! Int
        let indx = NSIndexPath(forRow: ind, inSection: 0)

//Тут код парсинга ответа
        allposts[ind].postliked = true //Вношу в массив (из которого таблица берёт значения) новое состояние лайка для данного поста
//----------------------

        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indx], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    }
```

Всё обновляется как надо. Срабатывает нужная ячейка, данные берутся из массива и выводятся в этой ячейке. За исключением одной проблемы:

**Проблема:** при обновлении нужной ячейки таблица немного скроллится вверх или вниз. Я погуглил и узнал, что проблема в разной высоте ячеек. Из-за этого происходит смещение. Так как таблица считает высоту согласно этому значению:

`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250.0`

Это усреднённое значение. Если поставить больше, то это сработает для некоторых ячеек. Но бывают очень длинные ячейки, так что нужно какое-то решение. Но решения я не нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все действительно из-за `estimatedRowHeight`. Пример для таблицы с фиксированным количеством данных, Swift 3.0:

1 создаем массив с значениями для каждой ячейки

```
var rowHeights = [CGFloat](repeating: 250.0, count: 300) //собственно, на этапе создания значение роли не играет
```

2 получаем реальную высоту ячейки, которая должна быть и меняем в массиве:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    rowHeights[indexPath.row] = cell.frame.height
}
```

3 подсовываем необходимые значения в `estimatedHeightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return rowHeights[indexPath.row]
}
```

4 при обновлении ячейки по индексу нет лишнего скролла.