# Как определить высоту хедера таблицы, у которого высота динамическая?

Tags: xcode, swift

Проблема в том, что у меня есть таблица, у которой ячейки имеют динамическую высоту. Т.е. ячейка кастомная и в сториборде её дизайн построен на констрейнтах. При загрузке таблице из интернета подгружается контент, который загружается в массив и потом таблица обновляется и ячейки заполняются, а высота их зависит от содержимого и может сильно варьироваться.

Сначала я столкнулся с проблемой, что из-за разной высоты при обновлении одной из ячеек таблица немного скроллилась. Мне помогли решить эту проблему [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568271/207604)

И казалось бы проблема решена. Но теперь я добавил к своей таблице хедер. И у него тоже высота динамически меняется. Как я понимаю, чтобы не было сдвига и таблица не скролилась при обновлении ячеек, мне нужно внести следующие строки в viewDidLoad:

```swift
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = ?
```

Но мне нужно узнать высоту хедера. Как это сделать? Если я делаю так:

```swift
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = view.frame.height
}
```

то я получаю высоту, которую задал изначально сам же во viewDidLoad. А мне нужна реальная высота хедера с учётом всего контента, который там есть.

Answer (score 1):

estimatedSectionHeaderHeight нужен для улучшения производительности загрузки table view. Можно указать среднее значение, тогда некоторые расчеты геометрии будут происходить во время скроллинга.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Вопрос совершенно не о том. А о том, как узнать высоту хедера. Но в принципе уже не актуален, так как я нашёл альтернативу хедеру.

Answer (score 1):

Если ты используешь автолейаут, можешь использовать метод     systemLayoutSizeFittingSize ,
он позволяет рассчитать фактическую высоту вью

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: А где именно его вызывать?